# VRP package for R

Tags: vehicle-routing, r

I work almost exclusively in R and Rstudio, and have found it to be an excellent ecosystem for data analysis and OR, including discrete event simulation, Monte Carlo simulation, MILP, and the Traveling Salesman Problem. The ONLY gap I see is, no library for the Vehicle Routing Problem and variants.

Anybody know of a VRP package in R?  I may need to undertake writing functions implementing VRP if I can't find a ready package.

Comment: Does the  Concorde TSP Solver not fill your needs (doesn't handle your desired type of VRPs)? R interface to  Concorde TSP Solver is available https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSP/TSP.pdf and https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSP/versions/1.1-7/topics/Concorde

Comment: Your chances of finding something like that in other languages (like Python) are higher. But if you need it in R and you find no luck, check [this link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/vehicle-routing-problem/) and maybe contact the authors

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I use that package for TSP, but I have the need for a number of capacitated VRP variants.

Comment: @EhsanK I know I could use Google ortools for Python, but there would be significant transition costs to moving large workflows from R to Python at this time.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The package [`netgen`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/netgen/versions/1.3) (v1.3) can be used to generate networks and benchmark instances of VRP and TSP.

As [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/r-shiny-application-capacitated-vehicle-routing-problem-shevade) shows it is also possible to solve a variant of VRP (CVRP) in R Shiny, which is another package used for interactive modelling/applications.

Comment: The Shiny app looks like it has two CVRP algorithms behind it: sweep and GA.  I have used Shiny quite a bit, but it still looks like the author had to write the algo himself in R and include that in the Shiny app code.  Not a big deal, but at least I know that is what is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is a bit late now, but recently I have been developing a package for solving large instances of the **capacitated multiple-depot vehicle routing problem** with mileage constraints, which is available here: [vrpoptima -  Genetic Solver for a Capacitated Multiple-Depot Vehicle Routing Problem with Mileage Constraints](https://gitlab.com/vikplamenov/vrpoptima/)

This is actually a generalization of the classical single-depot vehicle routing problem, as in the current version we could have unique positions for each agent (vehicle) and also impose mileage constraints on each agent. In case anyone is interested in testing and extending this package, please do let me know. Hope this helps someone in the future.